# I use pickle for dump dictionary (address book) can't remove keys

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I'm trying to create a addressbook, but I have a problems:

1. When I start program and add key(contact), I can't delete it after I added it.
2. I can delete keys(contact) only after restart program(quit and start).
3. When I try delete one key(after restart) program deletes all keys.

Example running test program from command-line:

```
[user@arch Python]$ python3 addres_book.py
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: l
{}
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: a
{}
Enter the name: alex
Enter the number: 122
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: r
{'alex': 122}
Enter the name of contact: alex
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: l
{'alex': 122}
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: a
{'alex': 122}
Enter the name: trump
Enter the number: 134
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: q
[user@arch Python]$ python3 addres_book.py
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: l
{'alex': 122, 'trump': 134}
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: r
{'alex': 122, 'trump': 134}
Enter the name of contact: trump
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
Enter function: l
{}
What to do?:
l - full list
a - add a contact
r - remove contact
s - search contact
q - quit
```

Program code:

```
import os
import pickle

addressbook = {}

home = os.environ['HOME']
path = home + '/.local/share/addressbook'
addressbookfile = path + '/' + 'addressbook.data'

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.mkdir(path)

while True:
    print("What to do?: ")
    print("l - full list")
    print("a - add a contact")
    print("r - remove contact")
    print("s - search contact")
    print("q - quit")

    answer = str(input("Enter function: "))

    if answer == 'l':
        f = open(addressbookfile, 'rb')
        storedfile = pickle.load(f)
        print(storedfile)

    elif answer == 'a':
        f = open(addressbookfile, 'rb')
        storedfile = pickle.load(f)
        print(storedfile)
        name = str(input("Enter the name: "))
        number = int(input("Enter the number: "))
        addressbook[name] = number
        f = open(addressbookfile, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(addressbook, f)
        f.close()

    elif answer == 'r':
        f = open(addressbookfile, 'rb')
        storedfile = pickle.load(f)
        print(storedfile)
        f = open(addressbookfile, 'rb')
        storedfile = pickle.load(f)
        delanswer = str(input("Enter the name of contact: "))
        del storedfile[delanswer]
        f = open(addressbookfile, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(addressbook, f)
        f.close()

    elif answer == 's':
        f = open(addressbookfile, 'rb')
        storedfile = pickle.load(f)
        search = input("Enter the data: ")
        searchresult = storedfile.get(search)
        print(searchresult)

    elif answer == 'q':
        break

    else:
        continue
```

Comment: You modify ``storedfile`` (``del storedfile[delanswer]``), but write ``addressbook`` (``pickle.dump(addressbook, f)``).

Comment: In addition, I don't understand why you do `f = open(addressbookfile, 'rb')` twice. You also redefine the file object without closing the file after reading. Look into context managers and reading files using `with`